# How can I combine ember-bootstrap and ember-autoresize?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-bootstrap

I would like to add the attribute `autoresize=true` to a textarea that is drawn using [ember-bootstrap](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/#/components/forms) in order to use [ember-autoresize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-autoresize).

[As you can see here](https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap/blob/master/addon/components/base/bs-form/element/control/textarea.js), this attribute is not bound, so I cannot simply add it to my template.

I've tried to manipulate the yielded control like so:

```
{{#bs-form formLayout="vertical" model=email as |form|}}
    {{#form.element controlType="textarea" property="textEdit" as |el|}}
        {{el.control autoresize=true}}
    {{/form.element}}
{{/bs-form}}
```

But this only works for classNames, not attributes.

What is the simplest way of achieving what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do it.

Both examples assume `ember-bootstrap` and `ember-autoresize` are installed.

## 1. Ad-hoc approach: no configuration needed, but less convenient to use

Use "Custom controls" described [here](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/api/classes/Components.FormElement.html).

Here's an example:

```
{{#bs-form formLayout="vertical" model=email as |form|}}
    {{#form.element controlType="textarea" property="textEdit" as |el|}}
        {{textarea autoresize=true id=el.id value=el.value class="form-control"}}
    {{/form.element}}
{{/bs-form}}
```

Demo: https://ember-twiddle.com/4860f5d660dceadc804495d2720f69f6?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C

## 2. Robust approach: configuration needed, but more convenient to use

Override [the original textarea component](https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap/blob/master/app/components/bs-form/element/control/textarea.js).

Here's the path for the Classic project structure. For Pods or Module Unification, the path will be different.

```
app/components/bs-form/element/control/textarea.js
```

Inside that file, do what the [autoresize textarea component](https://github.com/adopted-ember-addons/ember-autoresize/blob/latest/addon/ext/text-area.js) does, but on top of Ember-Bootstrap's textarea component:

```
import BootstrapTextareaComponent from 'ember-bootstrap/components/bs-form/element/control/textarea';
import AutoResizeMixin from 'ember-autoresize/mixins/autoresize';
import { computed, get } from '@ember/object';
import { isEmpty, isNone } from '@ember/utils'; 

export default BootstrapTextareaComponent.extend(AutoResizeMixin, {
  autoresize: true,
  shouldResizeHeight: true,
  significantWhitespace: true,
  autoResizeText: computed('value', 'placeholder', {
    get() {
      var placeholder = get(this, 'placeholder');
      var value = get(this, 'value');
      var fillChar = '@';

      if (isEmpty(value)) {
        return isEmpty(placeholder) ? fillChar : placeholder + fillChar;
      }

      if (isNone(value)) {
        value = '';
      }

      return value + fillChar;
    }
  })
});
```

Then you can invoke the Bootstrap textarea component normally:

```
{{#bs-form model=this formLayout="vertical" as |form|}}
  {{form.element label="Inline" placeholder="Enter description..." property="appName" controlType="textarea"}}
{{/bs-form}}
```

Demo: https://ember-twiddle.com/693209c5fd4c2eeae765827f42dbd635?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C

The above code will enable autoresizing to all Ember-Bootstrap textareas. If you need granular control, you can also remove `autoresize: true` from the component definition. This will let you enable autoresizing individually by passing `autoresize=true` into the `{{form.element}}` component invocation.

Comment: The first implementation would be awesome, but `form.element` already adds the form element, so your implementation will add the form element inside a form element (e.g. textarea inside textarea).
    
The second option looks good too, although foreign to me. However, it results in _"Failed to create an instance of 'component:bs-form/element/control/textarea'. Most likely an improperly defined class or an invalid module export."_ Because I don't understand exactly how this should work, I cannot fix this on my own, even if the mistake is minor.

Comment: `autoresize` without `.js` works. Unfortunately, the actual mixin does not.

Comment: You could also extend Ember Bootstrap with a custom `textarea-autoresize` control type. [ember-bootstrap-power-select](https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap-power-select) might give you some inspiration for that one.

Comment: This comment thread is [being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386168/what-if-someone-is-being-extremely-rude-but-ends-up-answering-correctly).

Comment: You don't need to inherit anything other than value. In order for the textarea to respect `formLayout`, it simply needs `class="form-control"`. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I've fixed the second approach and added a demo.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like using `ember-bootstrap` and `ember-autoresize` together **will not work**, because even adding the `ember-autoresize` mixin does not autoresize the textarea, although the mixin is applied successfully as evidenced the class added by `ember-autoresize`.

Perhaps both plugins trying to manupulate the textarea causes conflicts. Perhaps the latter is not compatible with the former in combination with Ember 3.11.

**Alternatively**, You can hack a solution together by manipulating `data-min-rows` on input, like this [codepen jquery example](https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/frudD).

Quoted for brevity:

```
// Applied globally on all textareas with the "autoExpand" class
$(document)
    .one('focus.autoExpand', 'textarea.autoExpand', function(){
        var savedValue = this.value;
        this.value = '';
        this.baseScrollHeight = this.scrollHeight;
        this.value = savedValue;
    })
    .on('input.autoExpand', 'textarea.autoExpand', function(){
        var minRows = this.getAttribute('data-min-rows')|0, rows;
        this.rows = minRows;
        rows = Math.ceil((this.scrollHeight - this.baseScrollHeight) / 16);
        this.rows = minRows + rows;
    });
```

Bootstrap adds jQuery either way. Might as well use it.

Comment: "*It looks like using ember-bootstrap and ember-autoresize together will not work*" -- this is false. The other answer has a working demo.

Comment: "*Bootstrap adds jQuery either way.*" -- this is false. Modern Bootstrap is not dependant on jQuery, and neither is `ember-bootstrap`.